# How to set User Control in layout panel in on click event

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am using a ribbon control an using bar item click and Dock layout manager I am calling tab but not able to set user control in it.

```
private void BarButtonItem_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    ActivateOrCreate("Company");
}

private void BarButtonItem_ItemClick_1(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ItemClickEventArgs e) {
    ActivateOrCreate("Branch");
}

private void ActivateOrCreate(string caption) {
    LayoutPanel layoutPanel = DockTabbed.GetItems().OfType<LayoutPanel>().Where(x => String.Equals(x.Caption, caption)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (layoutPanel == null) {
        layoutPanel = new LayoutPanel() { Caption = caption };
        layoutPanel.Content = new TextBlock() { Text = caption };
        DockTabbed.DockController.Dock(layoutPanel, TabbedView, DevExpress.Xpf.Layout.Core.DockType.Fill);
    }
    DockTabbed.Activate(layoutPanel);
}
```

in this I want to show User Control in layout panel.

Comment: layout panel does not needs to Controls.add method? Winfreem controls usually use this method to showing a control or usercontrol!

Answer (score 0):

Winform controls usually use Controls.add method to adding and showing a control or usercontrol! 
use like this:

```
layoutPanel.Controlss.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = caption, Size=new Size(x,y),... };
```